# Query regarding LIKE clause and Select Statement in SQLworkbench

Tags: mysql, select, join, mysql-workbench, sql-like

i want to retrieve data from the database by performing eg: following query:

```
  Select * from Employee emp
inner join Department dept on emp.empid=dept.empid
where dept.OrderID like '%1' OR
      dept.OrderID  like '%,1' OR
      dept.OrderID  like '%,1,%' OR
      dept.OrderID  like '1,%'
order by ..;
```

** Above conditon is--> 1 OR 2,1 OR 2,1,3 OR  1,2

Instead of **'1'** in above query,i want to pass select statement (**select OrderID from Orders where OrderName= 'ABCD'**).

I have tried but not getting it syntax wise.
Please Anyone can suggest me how to perform this correctly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     Select * from Employee emp
    inner join Department dept on emp.empid=dept.empid
    where dept.OrderID like CONCAT('%', (select OrderID from Orders where OrderName= 'ABCD')) OR
          dept.OrderID  like CONCAT('%,', (select OrderID from Orders where OrderName= 'ABCD')) OR
          dept.OrderID  like CONCAT('%,', (select OrderID from Orders where OrderName= 'ABCD'), ',%') OR
          dept.OrderID  like CONCAT((select OrderID from Orders where OrderName= 'ABCD'), ',%')
order by ..;
```